# Footer Not Sticking To The Bottom Of The Page

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

My footer is not sticking to the bottom of the page. I have already tried the following:

```
footer { /* position must be absolute and bottom must be 0 */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

footer {
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #00A;
    z-index: 150;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
```

None of these solutions (found on stackoverflow) have worked out for me so far so I have made a codepen with what I have:

http://codepen.io/sredmond/pen/revjdv

If you expand the code pen so that you see more of the result than the code you will see that it stays

```
NAVBAR

JUMBOTRON

CONTENT

FOOTER
<!--


Random white space


-->
```

What I want it to do is go like this:

```
NAVBAR

JUMBOTRON

CONTENT









FOOTER
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `.row` in `div` inside `footer`, maybe row class override your position setting.

Not:

```
<footer class="row"></footer>
```

But:

```
<footer><div class="row"></div></footer>
```

And then:

```
footer { 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; 
}
```

**EDIT**

So you need flexbox (or tables, flexbox is simplier but less backward compatible):

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Project</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/Home/Terms">Terms Of Service</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <li>
                        <a class="btn" href="https://www.facebook.com/Tech-U-276023285879783/" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','facebook')"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/TechUHost?s=09" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','twitter')"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="btn" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=TechU" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','android')"><span class="fa fa-android"></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm text-center">
                    <li class="social-icons">
                        <a class="btn" href="https://www.facebook.com/Tech-U-276023285879783/" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','facebook')"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
                        <a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/TechUHost?s=09" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','twitter')"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
                        <a class="btn" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=TechU" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','android')"><span class="fa fa-android"></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">

        <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content-body">

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="text-center">Portfolio</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 text-center bottom-30">
                <h4 class="bold">PeppNation</h4>
                <a href="http://www.peppnation.techuhost.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/Assets/Images/Images/Portfolio/PeppNation.png" width="300"/>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 text-center bottom-30">
                <h4 class="bold">Brock Report - Publications Page</h4>
                <a href="http://brockreport.com/publications.aspx" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/Assets/Images/Images/Portfolio/BrockReport.png" width="300"/>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 text-center bottom-30">
                <h4 class="bold">Camp BASIC</h4>
                <a href="http://campbasicdev.dev2.nsrit.com/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/Assets/Images/Images/Portfolio/CampBasic.png" width="300"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <footer class="content-footer">
              <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                    <h4 class="bold">TechU</h4>
                    <p><a href="/Home/Terms">Terms Of Service</a></p>
                    <p>&copy; 2016 - TechU</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <h4 class="bold">Contact Information</h4>
                    <p>Phone: <strong><a href="tel:4142555423">(414) 255-5423</a></strong></p>
                    <p>Email: <strong><a href="mailto:samjredmond@yahoo.com">samjredmond@yahoo.com</a></strong></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <h4 class="bold">Business Hours</h4>
                    <p>Monday - Friday: <strong>9 a.m. - 5 p.m. CST</strong></p>
                    <p>Saturday & Sunday: <strong>Closed</strong></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs footer-social-button-align">
                        <li>
                            <a class="btn" href="https://www.facebook.com/Tech-U-276023285879783/" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','facebook')"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/TechUHost?s=09" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','twitter')"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="btn" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=TechU" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','android')"><span class="fa fa-android"></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm">
                        <li class="social-icons">
                            <a class="btn" href="https://www.facebook.com/Tech-U-276023285879783/" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','facebook')"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
                            <a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/TechUHost?s=09" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','twitter')"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
                            <a class="btn" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=TechU" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','engagement','android')"><span class="fa fa-android"></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
      </footer>

    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

&CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 0;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.body-content {
    height: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%
}

.content-body {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.content-footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: So it seems like that worked, but not quite the way I wanted: http://codepen.io/sredmond/pen/revjdv is there any way I can get that footer within the body-content container?

Comment: Position fixed always tie element to window, if you wan't it to be part of element you will need to use 'absolute' positon. But you need to remember that both are independent from other elements, so if your footer grows up in height while viewport width change - it will overlap on your content.

Comment: You want this footer to be fixed on bottom of page and have this body-content container background under it always?

Comment: So if you go to the codepen now I did a ghetto version of what I want it to look like but the solution needs to be responsive (http://codepen.io/sredmond/pen/revjdv)

Comment: Thank You, this has helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this many times and it works perfect for me.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your html and your body tag dont expand to the bottom of the screen, if you have no content. To make your html expand to the bottom add this css:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0; /* removes any margin (especially at the bottom) */
   padding:0; /* removes any padding (especially at the bottom) */
   height:100%; /* will make it expand to the end */
}
```

Comment: Fixed position has no relation with body height;

Comment: Thats just the snippet that I always use. maybe body has nothing to do with it and "html" alone is good enough. Feel free to edit my solution if you are sure.